# Wrong logic in while loop? (Python)

Tags: python, logic

logically this makes sense but does not work.

```
dice = 0
while True:
    dice = int(input("enter dice: "))
    if (dice != 4 or dice != 6 or dice != 8 or dice != 10 or dice != 12 or dice != 20):
        print("invalid")
    elif (dice == 4 or dice == 6 or dice == 8 or dice == 10 or dice == 12 or dice == 20):
        print("valid")
        break
    
print("Accepted dice")
```

I keep getting the invalid print statement. Want to have it as a loop until one of the correct die is selected.

Comment: The logic in your first `if` is flawed, it will always evaluate as true. Take `dice != 4 or dice != 6`, it can never be false, the first part will only be false if `dice == 4` but that makes the second part true

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 1):

use a flag, as mentioned in the comment your original first if is flawed ... if you just want to fix it then you can change your or's to and's

```
dice_is_valid = dice in {4,6,8,10,20}
if dice_is_valid:
  ...
else:
  print("invalid")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with using an `or` statement here. Take for example an input of `4`. `4 != 4` if obviously false, but then it evaluates `4 != 6` which is true. No matter what you input that first condition will always be true because of this. Instead just use an `else` statement like so

```
dice = 0
while True:
    dice = int(input("enter dice: "))
        print("invalid")
    if (dice == 4 or dice == 6 or dice == 8 or dice == 10 or dice == 12 or dice == 20):
        print("valid")
        break
    else:
        print("invalid")
    
print("Accepted dice")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dice_var = 0
a = [4,6,8,10,12,20]
while True:
    dice_var = int(input("Enter the dice value ;"))
    if dice_var in a:
        print("Valid Value !!!!")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid Value !!!!")
print("Accepted Dice")
```